# Using Axios interceptor to stop requests and check for token expiration

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest, axios

I am trying to see if the token expired and if so, send a refresh request and only then continue the execution.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  let accessToken = getAccessToken()

  if (accessToken && user) {
    config.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    config.headers['cache-control'] = `no-cache`

    const { exp } = jwtDecode(accessToken)

    if (Date.now() > exp * 1000) {
      refreshAccessToken().then(() => { return config }) // wait for refresh
    } else {
      return config
    }
  }

}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

This is a refresh token function with a promise:

```
function refreshAccessToken() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

    if (refreshing) return resolve('refresh in progress')

    refreshing = true
    let refreshToken = getRefreshToken()

    let response = await serverTokenRefresh(refreshToken)
    if (response.success) {
      setAccessToken(response.accessToken)
      response.email = user
      setLocalStorageUser(response)
      refreshing = false

      return resolve('refresh successful')
    } else {
      await logOut()
      refreshing = false

      return reject(Error('refresh fail: ' + response.message))
    }
  })
}
```

For some reason Axios doesn't want to wait until the refresh function finishes and doesn't send out any call to the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing a literal `return` in `      refreshAccessToken().then(() => { return config }) // wait for refresh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that in your first callback function it needs to be returned as a `Promise` or for it to be declared `async`:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
  let accessToken = getAccessToken()

  if (accessToken && user) {
    config.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    config.headers['cache-control'] = `no-cache`

    const { exp } = jwtDecode(accessToken)

    if (Date.now() > exp * 1000) {
      await refreshAccessToken(); // wait for refresh
      return config;
    } else {
      return config
    }
  }

}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

Comment: Hey, can you tell me why you are doing this `exp * 1000`?

Comment: @AliHussnain That was presented by the OP, so you'd have to ask him. My part in this was to provide a way for async/await to be applied correctly to this problem. Having said that, I would assume that `exp` is measured in seconds but `Date.now` returns a value in milliseconds. Multiplying `exp` by 1000 converts that value into milliseconds so that a proper comparison can be made.